# Jquerying using child selectors

Tags: php, jquery

I have a div being populated from PHP i'm trying to bind all the input boxes in a div to variables, (I do not wish to use serialize) how can I use Jquery to select each one and bind it to a variable such as

```
var location_id = $('#Wednesday').find('input').nth-child(0);
var static_id  =$('#Wednesday').find('input').nth-child(1);
```

something of that nature thanks!

```
<div id='Wednesday' class='ui-widget-content ui-state-default' name='' value=''>  ";

echo "<input name='".$day."_".$locationid."_locationID' value='".$locationid."'  type='hidden'> ";
echo "<input name='".$day."_".$locationid."_static' value='".$static."'  type='hidden'> ";
echo "<input name='".$day."_".$locationid."_primary' value='".$first_always."' type='hidden'> ";
echo "<input name='".$day."_".$locationid."_all_locations' value='".$all_locations."' type='hidden'> ";

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputs = $('#Wednesday').find('input');

var location_id = inputs.eq(0).val();
var static_id  = inputs.eq(1).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

As a side note (since you already have your answer), any time I see input names of a form similar to what you have:

```
'name="' . $day . '_' . $location_id . '_locationID"'
```

It screams out to me that this might be a case where you should be using array-style form inputs like this:

```
'name="locationID[' . $day . '][' . $location_id . ']"'
```

That way in PHP, you already have a nice array built for you in `$_POST` and you don't need to `explode()` to build arrays out of all the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.eq` instead of `.nth-child()`.

Comment: that gives me [Object object] as a return value.

Comment: @Edward what do you want exactly?  How about `.eq(number).val()`?